# How to declare constant values in nsarray in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I had declared constant `NSArray` like the below way.

```
static NSArray* const myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"obj1",@"obj2",@"ibj3",@"obj4",@"obj5",nil];
```

But it shows an error "Initiliser elements are Not Compile time constants".
So I declared like this.But I got the error.

Please help This Case.

Thanks.

Comment: try to use singleton class, if the simple `#define MyConstantArray [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil]` is  not good enough for you.

Comment: remove static... and you are done.

Comment: @holex You don't need a singleton to have a file level global variable (which is what a static is). Using a macro is definitely not what is wanted for this.

Comment: @12345: plz specify your exact requirement... want a shared / singleton class with array or a local constant array in a method or in a class?

Comment: I want to declare a contstant Array in Constants.h class,declare that class ,I want to use that array..

Answer (score 7):

Since `NSArrays` are heap-allocated objects, you cannot create them in a static context. You can declare the variables, and then initialize them in a method.

So, you can do this way :-

```
static NSArray *myStaticArray = nil;

- (void) someMethod
{
  if (myStaticArray == nil)
  {
    myStaticArray = [[NSArray alloc] init...];
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you cannot use this to solve your problem. it is **100% constant**, because the `NSArray` is immutable, and it is also **100% static**.

---

**GlobalConstant.h** file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// EDITED : __unused static NSArray *_myGlobalArray;

@interface GlobalConstant : NSObject

+ (NSArray *)myGlobalArray;

@end
```

---

**GlobalConstant.m** file:

```
#import "GlobalConstant.h"

@implementation GlobalConstant

+ (NSArray *)myGlobalArray {

    static NSArray *_myGlobalArray = nil; // EDITED

    @synchronized (_myGlobalArray) {
        if (_myGlobalArray == nil) {
            _myGlobalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil]; // here is your array...
        }
        return _myGlobalArray;
    }
}

@end
```

---

...and your array will be available in every class which includes the `GlobalConstant.h` file, you can reach the array like

```
NSArray *_globalArray = [GlobalConstant myGlobalArray];
```

Comment: Do not declare the static in the .h file. Every .m that includes this header will get it's own copy of the static. Since this static array is only to be used internally by the GlobalConstants.m you should move the declaration to the .m file.

Comment: You should initialize the variable to `nil` to be safe. `static NSArray *_myGlobalArray = nil;`

Comment: Is it really necessary to have that @synchronized for a NSArray? Aren't NSArrays already thread safe?  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html if this is true, by doing this you are making this method slow.

Comment: @RubberDuck, as you can see that the `_myGlobalArray` pointer is synchronised only in this method. the type of the object behind this pointer does not matter at all. so, the fact, you have referred, is totally independent from it.

Answer (score 3):

To create the static array you can make use of the `initialize` method. This is a special class method that every class has. It is called the first time a class is referenced in any way and before any other code in the class is executed.

```
static NSArray* myArray = nil;

@implementation SomeClass

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [SomeClass class]) {
        myArray = @[ @"obj1", @"obj2", @"obj3", @"obj4", @"obj5" ];
    }
}

// rest of methods

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

and, to save typing, you can use `NSArray* myArray = @[ @"obj1", @"obj2", @"ibj3", @"obj4", @"obj5" ];`